# Como codificar um número em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar um número codificado para o utilizador.

Tenho várias linhas nas minhas tabelas e queria codificar  (só do lado do utilizador) os ID's. Fui a procura de funções para isso mas só encontrei  `md5` e `sha1` mas essas geram chaves muito grandes.

Há alguma que gere uma chave curta (+/- 6 a 8 digitos ou caracteres)?

Comment: Parece que você quer apenas mascarar o ID, se for isto apenas, você pode "somar" um numero, algo do tipo, o id é 11 e você soma `28900 + 11 = 28911`, assim já seria um jeito de mascarar. Com `md5`, `sha1` ou `crypt` você não pode "decodificar". Você pode tentar usar o [crypy](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.crypt.php) com `Standard DES`

Comment: Se é importante não mostrar o ID então ele não deveria ser usado no front, mesmo mascarado. Qual o problema de se ver o ID? Talvez seja um erro de lógica.

Comment: é um site de vendas online com produtos de uma loja, então preciso do id ao longo de todo o processo(compra, carro, e historico) para poder fazer tudo desde mostrar ao utilizador até finalizar a compra, então mostrar o id do produto ou até o ide da compra pode passar informações de quanto produtos temos ou e tambem quantas vendas vizemos, então a ide de codificar esses id's seria nesse sentido.

Comment: Não sei o motivo de "encriptar" tornando o ID um numero de X dígitos e não usar as funções próprias para tal. Isso não incrementa segurança no sistema. Alem do mais, se o usuário tem acesso ao ID, você está usando cookie, e nada impede o usuário de alterar o ID 123456 para 654321...

Comment: Filipe Moraes, isso não é erro de lógica. O propósito é comercial. No banco de dados pode ter um ID com 200 caracteres com numeros, letras, caracteres especiais, etc, mas para mostrar para o cliente é inviável. Um código muito grande mesmo que somente numérico, também é um incômodo pois imagine o cliente no telefone falando com o atendimento ao consumidor. O suporte pede para o cliente soletrar o código do pedido.. Perde-se muito tempo no atendimento e complica, confunde.. bom,, acho que atendeu.. o caso do atendimento é um mero exemplo. Editei o título para algo mais apropriado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você comentou, o caso de "segurança" é impedir que seja possível deduzir o numero de produtos ou clientes, sugiro que use PHP. No caso você pode criar uma função em um documento e incluir este documento em todas páginas necessárias com [`include`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php), exemplos:

Exemplo das funções, usando uma soma simples (supondo que o nome seja helper.php):

```
<?php
define('MASK_SUM', 1288900);

function mascararId($id_sem_mask) {
    return MASK_SUM + $id_sem_mask;
}

function desmascararId($id_com_mask) {
    return $id_com_mask - MASK_SUM;
}
```

E você pode alterar o valor de `MASK_SUM` quando quiser.

Usando:

```
<?php
include 'helper.php';

$id = 10;

$maskId = mascararId($id);

echo 'Mascarado:', $maskId, '<br>';
echo 'Desmascarado:', desmascararId($maskId), '<br>';
```

Exemplo online no [ideone](http://ideone.com/7W34Eh)

Answer (score 2):

A utilização de um valor codificado e de acordo com o que entendi na sua pergunta, pode muito bem ser um `BITFIELD`. Se procurar a sua definição no WIKI encontrará:

> A bit field is a term used in computer programming to store multiple,
>   logical, neighboring bits, where each of the sets of bits, and single
>   bits can be addressed. A bit field is most commonly used to represent
>   integral types of known, fixed bit-width. A well-known usage of
>   bit-fields is to represent a set of bits, and/or series of bits, known
>   as flags.[citation needed] For example, the first bit in a bit field
>   can be used to determine the state of a particular attribute
>   associated with the bit field.

Resumindo... pode assegurar a utilização de multiplos conteúdos num único valor (simplificando, utilizando um inteiro que é mais imediato). Estes podem ser `BIT a BIT` o que define estados (on/off) ou valores em conjunto de bits, por exemplo num conjunto de 4 bits poderá armazenar de 0 a 15 (décimal).

Para o programador um `BITFIELD` é muito útil, pois quando bem implementados estes reduzem em muito as comunicações e o tamanho da informação a gravar numa base de dados.Num inteiro 32 bits podemos por exemplo passar 32 estados diferentes em apenas 4 bytes.

No seu caso específico, você coloca a questão como identificador para registos. Mais uma vez este tipo de mecanismo vai permitir e dependendo da sua imaginação, juntar mais do que um valor. O exemplo que coloco realizei em 10 minutos e é para 32 bits mas se precisar de amplitudes maiores pode por exemplo fazer o mesmo para valores 64 bits de 8 bytes. Criei um ficheiro `bitfield32.php` e lá escrevi esta classe com o mesmo nome:

```
class BitField32 {

    private $value;

    function __construct($value = 0) {
        $this->value = intval($value);
    }

    public function getHigh() {
        return ($this->value & 0xffff0000) >> 16;
    }

    public function getLow() {
        return $this->value & 0x0000ffff;
    }

    public function setHigh($value) {
        $hi16 = intval($value);
        if ($hi16 >= 0 && $hi16 < 0xffff) {
            $this->value = ($this->value & 0xffff) | ($value << 16);
        }
    }

    public function setLow($value) {
        $low16 = intval($value);
        if ($low16 >= 0 && $low16 < 0xffff) {
            $this->value = ($this->value & 0xffff0000) | $value;
        }
    }

    public function toHex() {
        return dechex($this->toHex());
    }

    public function toBits() {
        return decbin($this->value);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }

}
```

Penso que o código está bem explicativo , pelo que não documentei na esperança que você entenda o que está exposto. Agora para utilizar só precisa de...

```
require 'BitField32.php';
$bf = new BitField32();
$bf->setHigh(365);
$bf->setLow(2015);

echo $bf, " ... "," high:", $bf->getHigh(), " low:", $bf->getLow();
```

De acordo com este exemplo, consegue ter um identificador único, um inteiro de 32 bits no valor de **23922655** e com ele armazena dois campos de dois valores distintos que no exemplo são **365** e **2015**.

Se o exemplo fosse para um inteiro 64 bits podemos por exemplo ter dois ID's de 32 bits e assim consegues 'mascarar' no máximo dois valores de 32 bits.

No que apresento divido os 32 bits em dois. Os primeiros 16 bits para um valor e os segundos 16 bits para outro valor. Mas não tem de ser assim. O seu limite são 32 bits mas pode e dependendo da implementação desejada ter mais do que um elemento.

Penso até agora ter respondido a uma parte da sua resposta, mas fica ainda a faltar o MYSQL, que em parte está respondido, mas e as vantagens? Será que vale mesmo a pena ter este mecanismo do ponto de vista do MYSQL ou já agora para qualquer outra base de dados.

Um campo de INDEX em texto vs INDEX com um numérico, dizem os manuais e a experiência que são os numéricos de longe a melhor opção em especial a nível de performance. Quando protejamos uma implementação devemos ter isso em conta. Quando passamos a olhar para grandes base de dados começamos então a perceber o impacto que tem a utilização de um mecanismo como o `BITFIELD`. Hoje em dia o espaço de armazenamento e de comunicações em servidores é pago, portanto são mais uns motivos a adicionar.

Concluindo pois a minha resposta já vai longa, sendo que existia ainda muito a falar sobre este tema e se o motivo principal é mascarar valores aqui tens uma solução eficaz, com a capacidade de adicionar valor seguro em implementações futuras e com vantagens claras que não apenas mascarar.