# Como ter segurança em id exposto em links - PHP + Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, segurança

Linguagem PHP.

Tenho uma grid onde possuo em cada linha botões de editar e excluir aquele registro com ações em javascript passando o id daquele registro para efetuar a ação. Meu problema é relacionado a segurança uma vez que pode ter um usuário sacana que altera o id daquele botão e acesse dados indevidos ou o exclua. Como fazer de uma forma segura?

Exemplo de como está sendo feito:

Parte renderizada em HTML sai +/- assim (exemplo do q sairia do grid):

```
 <td>Dados1</td>
 <td>Dados2</td>
 <td><img src="editar.png" onclick="editar(1)"><img src="excluir.png"> onclick="excluir(1)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Dados3</td>
 <td>Dados4</td>
 <td><img src="editar.png" onclick="editar(2)"><img src="excluir.png"> onclick="excluir(2)"></td>
</tr>
```

e no javascript

```
function editar(id) {
   // chamada em ajax pra controller passando o id via post
}

function excluir(id) {
   // chamada em ajax pra controller passando o id via post
}
```

alguma sugestão de como fazer de forma segura sem expor o id para o usuario?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é o PHP Injection? Qual a diferença dele para o SQL Injection? E como evitá-lo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80699/o-que-%c3%a9-o-php-injection-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dele-para-o-sql-injection-e-como-evit)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como codificar um número em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45574/como-codificar-um-n%c3%bamero-em-php)

Comment: Vitor creio que isso resolva o seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45580/3635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde Amigo. Recentemente tive um dilema similar. seguindo seu exemplo de código eu resolvi usando a classe cryptoLib disponível em http://cryptolib.ju.je

1. Primeiro criamos as funções

```
 require("path/to/cryptolib.php");

 function tokenizer($id){
 $token = CryptoLib::encryptData($id, "token");
 return $token;
 }

 // Função simples para decodificar o token recebido após click no elemento

 function decodeToken($token){
 $decryptedString = CryptoLib::decryptData($token, "token");
 return $decryptedString;
 }
```

## EXEMPLO: No seu html o código pode ser aplicado da seguinte forma

```
<td>Dados1</td>
<td>Dados2</td>
<td><img src="e.png" onclick="editar(<? echo tokenizer($row["id"]) ?>)">
<img src="del.png"> onclick="excluir(<? echo tokenizer($row["id"]) ?>)">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dados3</td>
<td>Dados4</td>
<td>
<img src="e.png" onclick="editar(<? echo tokenizer($row["id"]) ?>)">
<img src="del.png"> onclick="excluir(<? echo tokenizer($row["id"]) ?>)">
</td>
</tr>
```

## HTML OUTPUT: No seu html renderizado o código fonte será similar ao exemplo abaixo:

```
<td>Dados1</td>
<td>Dados2</td>
<td><img src="e.png" onclick="editar("ctnbCH1FXdr41JYI9J82sXjGKbFvIUP3pshgL8KaZsYsEFqFco3NgimLy2xAj")">
<img src="del.png"> onclick="excluir("gimLy2xfUP3pshgL8KaZsYsEFqFco3NAjctnbCH1FXdr41JYI9J82sXjGKbFv")">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dados3</td>
<td>Dados4</td>
<td>
<img src="e.png" onclick="editar("IUPIUP3pshgL8KaZsYsEFqFco3NgimLy2xAj3pshgL8KaZsYsEFqFco3NgimLy2xAj")">
<img src="del.png"> onclick="excluir("8KaZsYsEFqFco3NgctnbCH1FXdr41JYI9J82sXjGKbFvIUP3pshgLimLy2xAj")">
</td>
</tr>
```

No seu CRUD em PHP. Utilize a função de validação do token:

$id = decodeToken($token);

A função retorna o id para usar na manipulação do CRUD.

Conclusão:

Ao chamar a função

```
tokenizer($row["id"]);
// O valor retornado para token
sXjGKbFvIUP3pshgLim8KaZsYsEFqFco3NgctnbCH1FXdr41JYI9J82Ly2xAj
```

Ao receber o token, enviado pelo javascript, chama a função

```
$id = decodeToken($token);
// se o valor do $row["id"] informado para a função tokenizer() for igual a "99".
// a função retornará o equivalente a:
$id = 99;
```

## Vantagens:

Toda vez que as páginas são renderizadas, o token gerado para cada $row{"id"] é único e aleatório.

Espero que isso ajude a sanar suas dúvidas.

Answer (score 1):

> Meu problema é relacionado a segurança uma vez que pode ter um usuário sacana que altera o id daquele botão e acesse dados indevidos ou o exclua[...]

Supondo que você somente permita a execução das devidas ações diante da validação do usuário, então não é uma questão de falha de segurança.

1. Se o usuário *X* pode alterar ou remover tal conteúdo então tudo vai
   bem.
2. Se por algum motivo você confiar em 'validações' externas e o PHP
       assumir que a requisição é verdadeira sem validar o usuário, então
       temos um problema.

---

Caso o usuário tenha acesso à ações ao conteúdo **1** e **2** e você tem um botão `delete.php?id=1`, mesmo alterando o ID, o usuário pode alterar o conteúdo sem problema. O link só não pode permitir que ele altere para o ID de um conteúdo que não seja dele e execute a ação.

Note que o usuário sempre verá a referência, mesmo que você tenha um hash para o ID.

Answer (score 0):

A parte que fica no cliente (JavaScript, HTML, CSS) sempre poderá ser manipulada, você precisa fazer a validação dos dados no lado do servidor (PHP, no seu caso), lá você terá o ID passado, basta checar se aquele usuário realmente poderá editar aquele elemento antes de fato editar.